# Is there anything faster than UIView Animations?

Tags: iphone, animation

Is there anything faster than UIView Animations? Mine are not keeping up,

I want to play a series of images, very fast. (i.e 10 in 80 milliseconds)

Any ideas?

As usual, greatly appreciated.

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a replacement for UIImageView's animationImages property, the second example on [this page](http://www.modejong.com/iPhone/) presents an alternative (as pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442076/method-for-animating-images-like-a-movie-on-iphone-without-using-mpmovieplayer)).

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the UIImageView animation images? Do you want transitions between your images? If not, there is no reason to use UIView Animations.

Now to play frame-based animations, I would suggest using the UIImageView object and add your images in its `animationImages` array. Not sure it will keep up with the framerates you require of course, especially if the images are large.