# Core Animation Image sequence

Tags: ios, iphone, image, core-animation

How would i go about creating an image sequence with core animation. I would like to:

add image1 for 1 second then remove image

add image2 for 2 seconds then remove image

add image1 for 3 seconds then remove

```
    CGImageRef image1 = [self getImage1];
    CALayer *image1Layer = [CALayer layer];
    image1Layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
    image1Layer.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    image1Layer.contents = (id)image1;


    CABasicAnimation *animation1 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"animation"];
    animation1.repeatCount = 0; 
    animation1.duration = 2.0;
    animation1.removedOnCompletion = YES; // i would like to remove image here
    animation1.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero; 
    [image1Layer addAnimation:animation1 forKey:nil];
```

The above code adds an image but does not remove it.

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to use CABasicAnimation for contents key:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animation.fromValue = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"].CGImage;
animation.toValue = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"].CGImage;
animation.duration = 1.0f;
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
//  animation.autoreverses = YES;
[image1Layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"contents"];
```

This animation will infinitely change the layer contents between image1 and image2. You may want to set `autoreverses` property for smoother transitions - test animation either ways and choose the option you like the best.

Comment: I am getting the error: cannot convert 'CGImage*' to 'objc_object*' in argument passing. And i would like to add about ten images and cut straight from one to the other. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: sorry, you need to explicitly cast cgimage to id - that should fix the error. To animate through 10 images you can use CAKeyFrameAnimation in a way similar to CABasicAnimation, you'll only need to provide an array of images to iterate through and array of keyTimes to control animations timing

Comment: @Vladimir- how can i play a sequence of an image from an array in your code.like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955031/sequencing-image-using-core-animation-recieving-memory-warnings... i have the same problem

Comment: @VivekSehrawat, you need to figure out method that will allow not to load all 100 images into memory. My solution cannot straightforwardly scale for that

Comment: @Vladimir- thanks, but can you elabroate the answer of brad lanson in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442076/method-for-animating-images-like-a-movie-on-iphone-without-using-mpmovieplayer

Comment: A working solution for many images without crashing out system memory is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442076/method-for-animating-images-like-a-movie-on-iphone-without-using-mpmovieplayer#answer-6077394

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this by using `CAKeyframeAnimation`. Follow the steps:

1. Create an UIImage array, and add images
2. Prepare `CAKeyframeAnimation` animation
3. Prepare `CALayer`
4. Add animation to the layer

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68727453/3124756)