# How to animate an image in a Mac OSX application?

Tags: macos, xcode4, core-animation, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

I want to set a basic animation for an image.ie when the application opens, an image to be shown in the window and after 1 second that image has to dissolve and show another. Can i do that using the transition filters in Xcode? If so, how? If not how can i implement that?

Thanks,

LS Developer

Comment: Isn't this just what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958952/core-animation-image-sequence