# Handle iOS Core Animation image sequence

Tags: ios, xcode

I want my my application to show an image and flash another after a while and keep it there can someone tell me what to add to the .h file considering the .m?

```
CGImageRef image1 = [self getImage1];
CALayer *image1Layer = [CALayer layer];
image1Layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
image1Layer.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
image1Layer.contents = (id)image1;

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
animation.fromValue = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"].CGImage;
animation.toValue = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"].CGImage;
animation.duration = 1.0f;
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
//  animation.autoreverses = YES;
[image1Layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"contents"];
```

based off of this question [Core Animation Image sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958952/core-animation-image-sequence)

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView can animate a series of images as standard. Just pass in an array of images to animationImages property.

I can't remember the exact names atm but take a look at the UIImageView documentation and you'll find it.

Comment: i've tried setting them to UIimages. i need specifics =)

Comment: Take a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/index.html in the section "Animating Images". You don't need any of your own animation code etc...

Comment: i'll give it a read. till then any hard code appreciated greatly =)

Comment: It's really simple. all the code is there in that one section.