# UIImageView animateImages Delay

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I'm kind of stuck with this problem. I have a UIImageView animation with 37 images where I show a glass filling with alcohol.
I initialize my image array in ViewDidLoad,

```
NSArray * GlassAnim  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SodaPour1" ofType:@"png"]],
                        [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SodaPour39" ofType:@"png"]],
                        nil];

imgGlass.animationImages = GlassAnim;
imgGlass.animationDuration = 2.5;
imgGlass.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imgGlass.animationRepeatCount=1;
[GlassAnim release];
```

Then I call **startAnimating** when user taps the screen. But the problem is that the animation has a half a second delay for the first time. Each image has a dimension of **330*372** pixels and the file size is **180KB** png files. Is there a better way to do this other than playing a video?.

Thanks.

Comment: One tip. You can use shorter form for an UIImage:  `[UIImage imageNamed:@"SodaPour18.png"]`

Comment: No considerable change. Is there a way doing this using CALayer animations?....

Comment: Mods don't answer questions at the request of users, so flagging for moderator attention isn't going to work.  If you want some attention for your question, I would HIGHLY suggest you 1) [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6762408/edit) your question to make your code fit without causing the scrollbars to appear (you *seriously* don't need all those damn UIIMage lines; cut out most of them, shorten the remaining and move them to the left) and then 2) put a bounty on your question.  You can read about bounties in the [faq#bounty].  Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge. I found the answer anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your answer deamonsarea?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for this as well. Can you please share it?

Comment: I Just posted my answer. Hope it will help you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go,

1. You start a Timer to change image names.

   ```
   timerAnimation = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.10 target:self
   selector:@selector(changeImagesAccordingly) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] 
   retain];
   ```
2. Rename the images in a sequence. I have 16 images.

   Eg:- "AnimationImg1.png", "AnimationImg2.png", "AnimationImg3.png"

   ```
   - (void)changeImagesAccordingly {
       if (iImgAnim<16) {
           imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                  pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"AnimationImg%d",iImgAnim] ofType:@"png"]];
           iImgAnim++;
       } else {
           [timerAnimation invalidate];
           iImgAnim=1;
       }
   }
   ```

That should do it :)

Comment: This answer is an okay first step as it does not decode all the images into memory before animating. You will likely still have some performance issues as it looks like your are tying to get about 20FPS with rather large images. For more info on FPS and performance, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880798/how-to-assemble-animation-from-an-array-of-images-with-the-highest-fps-possible/17128678#17128678

Comment: Thanks for the tip MoDJ. In my case I was able to solve it. But your answer should be the right one I guess.

Comment: Your approach is good enough as a first shot at it. Note that you can find my own impl of the same sort of timer based animation in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442076/method-for-animating-images-like-a-movie-on-iphone-without-using-mpmovieplayer/6077394#6077394